# background-image breaks browsers and doesn't work (invalid property value)

Tags: css, browser, background-image

Tested on Chromium and Firefox. Here's full address of the image, that breaks it: https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/Zy6h88J14S1Nxufykbs275yoVKM=/0x0:1920x1200/1820x1213/filters:focal(807x447:1113x753):format(webp)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/62249629/grinch1.0.jpg - can I do something to be sure it never happens? I know I can find image that works, but if user just pastes the URL, what can I do?

[image]

Edit: you can copy the address above an paste it in dev tools to see yourself.

Comment: try `"` around the url

Comment: @TemaniAfif, fun, I bet I tried it before and it didn't work, but it works now. Thank you